# RequireJS components sometimes not loading in my magento 2 site

Tags: javascript, magento, magento2, magento-2.3

I am currently running on magento 2.3 site, and finding that the site will sometimes load all of its Javascript components and dependencies properly, but sometimes fails to load.

IF you hard-refresh/clear your browser cache it works and all the errors disappear for that page, but if you browse the site it will throw the errors again after visiting a few pages.

Also page refresh errors are change. Below are few sample errors.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at observable_array.js:54

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disposableCustomerData' of undefined
    at customer-data.js:101

Comment: I also have the same issue!, How did you come to solve this?

Comment: Same issue... is there a solution¿